# Using delimiters with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I am having difficulties to understand preg_match function.An e.g is way better

```
$subject="XY=abC%3Fedr%3Damp;35"
```

I am trying to extract

> bC%3Fed

using preg_match and store it in variable

```
if(preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches))
            {
                $string = $matches[1];
            }
echo $string;
```

Here are the different variation that i use for $pattern

I want to use @ as a delimeter

```
@bC(.*?)@
@bC.*?@
```

I just don't understand why its not working , i guess something is wrong in the $pattern.

Please don't use complicated regex and try to fix my attempt as  the aim here is to understand how preg_match works and what is wrong here.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@` as the delimiter is OK, but the regex is wrong. I guess you want:

```
@(bC.*?)r@ // matches @bC and the following characters unless and 'r' (see comments)
```

A good starting point to learn the regex syntax is the [PCRE manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

---

*Example:*

```
$subject="XY=abC%3Fedr%3Damp;35";
$pattern="@(bC.*?)r@";

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
$string = $matches[1];

echo $string; // bC%3Fed
```

Comment: how you know it will be in $matches[0]

Comment: Its the first and only *"matching group"* that's why `$matches[0]`. If you are unsure use `var_dump($matches);`

Comment: Thanks the point is that i want to extract all characters between  bC and r.In real situation i don't know the exact number of characters to extract

Comment: Have updated the answer. Now it is `$matches[1]` <- we are using the `()` in pattern. Note the `?`. It is important, as otherwise the pattern would match until the latest `r` in string (if there are more). But you want the nearest `r`.. That's why the `?` - this is called *ungreedy matching*

Answer (score 1):

The ? after .* switches the greediness of the pattern. By default patterns are greedy, they try to find the longest match. So you .*? means any char, any count, smallest match. Because here is nothing after that will anchor it, the smallest possible match is an empty string.